# Paging without breaking group

Tags: mysql

In the application I will be processing data from a very large table in MySQL 5.7. I will be retrieving data about 2000 rows at a time.

The rows are linked with each other using `group_id` column - up to 3 rows in a group. So when I page over data I don't want to break the grouping, because the data does not make sense unless I have all the rows from the group.

```
id   group_id   data
---------------------------
1    25         item data
2    26         item data
3    26         item data
4    27         item data
5    27         item data
6    27         item data
7    29         item data
8    33         item data
9    33         item data
```

And I would retrieve data using a query similar to this.

```
select id, grouping_id, data
from table
limit <start>, 2000
```

Any thoughts on how I can page over data while retrieving whole groups?

Comment: what if a single group_id have 2000+ rows

Comment: At most 3 items in a single group_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is paging over distinct `group_id` values and doing self join to get rows in each selected group.

```
select t.id, t.group_id, t.data from table t
right join (
    select group_id 
    from table
    group by group_id -- or select distinct
    order by id
    limit <start>, 1000
) t_
on t.group_id = t_.group_id;
```

This way I am paging over `group_id`s instead of just rows.

Given that each group can contain up to 3 rows, in above example the number of rows retrieved per page would range from 1000 (if each group contains 1 row) up to maximum of 3000 rows (if each group contains 3 rows).

Answer (score 0):

Let see how we can solve this :

- `ROW_NUMBER()` we can find row/ count row number by group id
- `PARTITION BY` used for to reset above row number and count for new one
- `WITH`, common table expression we will select form group data `RowWithChunk`

```
WITH RowWithChunk AS (
    SELECT
        group_id,
        data,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id) AS row_num
    FROM
        table
)
SELECT
    group_id,
    data,
    row_num
FROM
    RowWithChunk
WHERE
    row_num <= 3

order by group_id

limit 0, pageSize;
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7, which unfortunately does not support common table expressions.

Comment: @sakura-bloom, sorry i tested this query with mysql 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, sorry for inconvenience